# Python, составить многопоточный код

Tags: python, многопоточность, threading

Приложение которое создает 3 потока и они должны бесконечно одновременно выполнять это

1. print ("1 секунда") (каждую секунду)
2. print ("2 секунды") (каждую 2 секунды)
3. print ("3 секунды") (каждую 3 секунды)
   при помощи библиотеки threading

вот как получилось у меня но почему-то в терминале выводится только "1"

```
import time
from threading import Thread
a = 1


def potok1():
  a = 1


while a == 1:
  time.sleep(1)
  print('1 cекунда')


def potok2():
  a = 1


while a == 1:
  time.sleep(2)
  print('2 секунды')


def potok3():
  a = 1


while a == 1:
  time.sleep(3)
  print('3 секунды')
th = Thread(target=potok1, args=())
th1 = Thread(target=potok2, args=())
th2 = Thread(target=potok3, args=())
th.start()
th1.start()
th2.start()
th.join()
th1.join()
th2.join()
```

Comment: У вас метка `[c++]` по ошибке или вас устроит код и на C++?

Comment: извините не заметил, по ошибке

Comment: у вас выравнивание съехало

Comment: как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Табуляции в питоне критически важны. Такой код просто висит на цикле `while` и не идёт дальше:

```
a = 1

def potok1():
  a = 1

# дальше отступ такой же, какой был у начала описания функции
# так что питон считает, что функция кончилась
# и следующий код находится уже вне функции,
# выполняется он сразу, а не когда вызывается функция

while a == 1: # <-- ВЫПОЛНЕНИЕ КОДА ЗАСТРЕВАЕТ ЗДЕСЬ!!!
  time.sleep(1)
  print('1 cекунда')
```

Правильно должно быть так - отступ у блока `while` должен соответствовать отступу **внутри** функции, это касается и остальных функций. Тогда цикл `while` попадёт внутрь функции, выполнение кода дойдёт до потоков, они запустятся:

```
a = 1

def potok1():
  a = 1

  while a == 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    print('1 cекунда')
```

Answer (score 2):

выводится только "1" потому что программа завершила главный поток.

добавьте

```
th.join()
th1.join()
th2.join()
```

Comment: можете скинуть полный код с внесенным изменением, у меня не получилось просто